# How to bind a Setter in Resources to multiple controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `UserControl` with, amongst other things, two `ComboBoxes`, which share the same `IsEnabled` property's definition:

```
<ComboBox.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource nullMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Path="ItemsSource"/>
        <Binding ElementName="aThirdIrrelevantComboBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.IsEnabled>
```

Basically, it says that if `this` combo box's `ItemsSource` is null **or** if `aThirdIrrelevantComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` is null, `this` combo box's `IsEnabled` is **false** (and true elseways).

So I have two combo boxes with that same exact definition (copy-pasted). **How can I avoid repeating this definition for each control that needs it?**

I tried creating a `Setter` in my `UserControl.Resources`, but I don't seem to know how to bind it.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:NullToEnabledMultiConverter x:Key="nullMultiConverter"/>
    <Setter Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled" x:Key="shpEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource nullMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ItemsSource"/>
                <Binding ElementName="aThirdIrrelevantComboBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This binding doesn't work, my combo boxes remain enabled:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled=IsEnabled="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource shpEnabled}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Setter` into a `Style` and name *that* instead:

```
<Style x:Key="ShpEnabledStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource nullMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ItemsSource"/>
                <Binding ElementName="aThirdIrrelevantComboBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then apply that `Style` to the relevant `ComboBox`(es):

```
<ConboBox Style="{StaticResource ShpEnabledStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to use a style. Is there an use for a `Setter` in resources?

Comment: What's wrong with using a `Style`? Did you know that you can base one `Style` on another `Style`? See the [`Style.BasedOn` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but well, I don't know, I don't feel like it semantically belongs in a Style. May be just me. Thanks anyway!